# How to delete all white spaces until first character?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Is there a simple way to delete all white spaces on a line until the first character on that line is met?

An example:

```
           #a list of comments
                # item 1
                # item 2
```

And I would like it to become:

```
#a list of comments
# item 1
# item 2
```

I know how to delete n characters (ex: `8x`) and to repeat the command (`.`), but how could I do without having to input the number of white spaces?

Comment: Related post: [Remove all arbitary spaces before a line in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4625598/438329)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can either visually select the lines and use

```
:'<,'>s/^\s*//
```

Which means 'substitute all of the whitespaces following the first column of the line by nothing'

Or go on the first line, use

- <kbd>0</kbd> to go on the first column
- <kbd>d^</kbd>  to delete until the first character of the line

And then go to the next line and use the dot command

Comment: Your first method is a bit too involved for me at this point :). A note to those using an international keyboard (ex US international), don't forget to press the space bar for `d^` after the `^`!

Comment: @calocedrus, `:h :substitute` is really the way to go in your case. Once you'll master `:substitute`, you'll have a good grasp of a key feature of the major `sed` *nix command.

Comment: Many good answers, and they worked for me, difficult to select one vs others! At this point (~ 1 month after I asked), @statox's answer seems to have received most votes so I'll select it as the answer, decision also supported by Luc's advice.

Answer (score 20):

#### This works for me.

<kbd>esc</kbd>
<kbd>:</kbd> to enter vim command mode

```
%s/^\s*//g
```

#### Meaning:

`%s/<REGEX TO REPLACE>/<REPLACEMENT TEXT>/` for string substitution

`g` for global (all lines)

Regex matching leading whitespace is `^\s*`

Voila

Comment: thats awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 19):

In addition to statox's methods, you can:

- Position the cursor at the beginning of the leading whitespace and type `dw`
- Position the cursor anywhere in the leading whitespace and type `diw`
- Position the cursor at the first non-space character of the line and type `d0`
- Visually select all the lines you want to move left, e.g., by typing `V` on the first line and moving the cursor to the last line, then executing `:left`

**Update**

What I actually usually do in such cases is:

- Visually select all the lines as above, type `<` to move them left by one shiftwidth, then type `.` until they're shifted all the way to the left margin.

Comment: For your second solution, how to quickly move to the first non-space character in the line? The solution selecting multiple lines is excellent.

Comment: @calocedrus As suggested in my answer `^`  allows you to go on the first non whitespace character of the line.

Comment: `:left` is my preferred method

Comment: Last suggestion works really well and is flexible

Answer (score 8):

Deleting a word at the beginning of the line will do the trick:

```
dw
```

If you want to repeat that for every line in the file that begins with whitespace:

```
:g/^ /norm dw
```

Comment: this only works if no line starts without leading spaces

Comment: yes. the purpose of the match on /^ / is to apply the dw command only on lines that start with a whitespace

Comment: Could you explain what this command does?  I know this is a regex match, what's the difference between :g/ and :s/?  And what does the '/norm dw' do?

Comment: `g` executes a command on every line that matches a given regexp. In this case it executes the `dw` command in normal mode (hence the `norm`). If you don't specifiy `norm` it will interpret the commands as ex commands.
`s` instead substitutes. `g/re/p` executes the `p` (print) ex command for every line matching a regexp. Here's where the name of the grep command comes from.

Comment: This is awesome. I've worked in vi for decades and didn't know this.

Answer (score 7):

A few variations on a theme:

#### Method(s) that will work in `vi`:

- Go to the first line that you want to manipulate.
- Count the lines that you want to manipulate —
  let’s say there are 17 of them. 
  Type `17<<`. 
  This will shift each of the following seventeen lines
  left by one shiftwidth (normally eight characters; i.e., one tab). 
  Assuming you still have lines with leading spaces,
  type **`.`** to repeat the shift command. 
  Type **`.`** repeatedly until all the spaces are gone.
- If you want to remove the leading spaces from all lines
  to the end of the buffer, use `<G` and then **`.`** repeatedly.
- Any common technique for identifying the end of the range
  will work similarly. 
  For example, with the text in your question,
  you could use `</2/` (and then **`.`** repeatedly).

#### Method that will work only in `vim`:

- Go to the first line that you want to manipulate.
- Type <kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
  to go into visual selection mode (mark the beginning of the range).
- Move to the end of the range.
- Type `9<`. 
  This will shift the selected lines left by nine shiftwidths. 
  As this will typically be 72 characters (9×8),
  there’s a good chance that that will do the job. 
  If you still have lines with leading spaces,
  type **`.`** to repeat the shift command (i.e., another72 characters).
- Or, if you know that you have lines
  with more than 72 leading spaces (or nine tabs), just use `99<`.

Answer (score 3):

Using vi you should be able to type

```
<Esc>:%left<CR>
```

to left-align the whole file.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I've edited your post with a little formatting (and expanded what I understood to be the `left` command). It might be worth adding some explanation with an [edit]—in particular, what if someone doesn't want to `:left` the whole file?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a single command to do it (starting in Normal mode, on the line you want to modify):

```
I<c-w><esc>
```

This switches to Insert mode and positions the cursor on the first non-whitespace character. Ctrl-w will then delete to the beginning of the line.

This can then be `.` repeated on any other line, from any column.

Answer (score 1):

In normal mode i use `d/\w<CR>` 
I often find my self using / or ? to make big surgical jumps/deletions/selections

Answer (score 0):

I've written a function for this (add this in your `.vimrc`) :

```
function RTS()
"Remove trailing spaces in every line"
    let nl = line('$')
    exe ":normal gg"
    for i in range(1, nl)
        exe ":normal 0d^j"
    endfor
endfunction
```

then call it whenever you want to use it:

```
:call RTS()
```

Comment: This looks pretty inefficient, and I don't see the need for a function here. You could do something similar with `:global/./normal! 0d^` (no `:execute` needed), or even `:%substitute/^\s*//`, or `:%left`, but these are already covered.

Comment: I suppose you're right about inefficiency, but it's just a solution that came to my mind and was not covered here.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering for this specific task, but I personally prefer `df<char>` and `dt<char>` or with `c` operator.

Once you are familiar with it, it deals with most cases more consistently by deleting from your cursor position to a specified character (`f` for inclusive, `t` for exclusive) at the cost of only one more keystroke than the optimal `d^` and involving no complex mind calculation (IMHO, you'd better avoid `F` and `T` for backward search which do not include the character under cursor, this places more burden on memory and mind).

e.g. some of my often used commands: `dt)` `df,` `cf`  etc. You only need to count characters or resort to Visual Mode (also remember using `f` or `t` to move cursor!) when there are multiple occurrences of the character, which seems to be a rare case for me. Also often we want to delete to a delimiter, such as `,` `;`  , which stands out clearly in the text, making obviously the argument of the command and even aiding quickly counting occurrences.